# How to successfully login using by php web service

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, parsing

Firstly I have two text fields first is login and second is password and one login button. I am using a storyboard and login button connected to another view controller by push segue. This time working in my project, Put username and password in textfield and select login button and print server response in console.
I want to login successfully after move another view and login is failed don't move another view.

## My php code

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
include('../conn.php');
 if($_POST)
{
$loginid = $_POST['loginid'];
$loginpassword = $_POST['loginpassword'];
$schoolid = substr_id($loginid);
$table = tb3($schoolid);//profile
$sql=mysql_query("select * from $table where ID = '".$loginid."' AND  PASSWORD = '".$loginpassword."'",$conn);

$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
      if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0)
      {
      echo '{"success":1}';
      }
      else 
      {
      echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"UserID and/or password is invalid."}';
      }
}
else 
{  
echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"UserID and/or password is invalid."}';
}
```

## My viewcontroller code

```
- (IBAction)Login:(id)sender {
if([[self.user_id text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.password text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {

} else {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sixthsenseit.com/school/project/ios/login.php"]];
    //create the Method "GET" or "POST"
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //Pass The String to server(YOU SHOULD GIVE YOUR PARAMETERS INSTEAD OF MY PARAMETERS)
    NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"loginid=%@&loginpassword=%@&",_user_id.text,_password.text, nil];

    //Check The Value what we passed
    NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", userUpdate);
    //Convert the String to Data
    NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //Apply the data to the body
    [request setHTTPBody:data1];
    //Create the response and Error
    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    //This is for Response
    NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);

    if(resSrt)
    {
        NSLog(@"got response");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"faield to connect");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I want to login successfully after move another view and login is failed don't move another view.` --> ?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik move to another view that mean "click Login button and by push segue move to home view controller"

Comment: ok if fail where you go

Comment: if fail alert show "Login is failed "

Comment: ok lets expain where you struck

Comment: Yes but problem is that Dipinkridhna Php code don't work with connect data base

Comment: my php code is different

Comment: you are not get any response from correct or not

Comment: Today code run and get response success

Comment: can you show the output `resSrt`

Comment: yes show output in resSrt

Comment: no bro , I am not asked that , show the result , you are in the correct way

Comment: Please help how to working fine my login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This line is wrong

```
NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"loginid=%@&loginpassword=%@&",_user_id.text,_password.text, nil];
```

> you are additionally added the `&` in your params ,this is not in **loginpassword=%@&** , you need to call like **loginpassword=%@** remove and send the request

use like

```
NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"loginid=%@&loginpassword=%@",_user_id.text,_password.text, nil];
```

> The problem is you are not serlize your JSON

so remove this line in your `NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];`

and I follow your Answer

```
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

        if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
        {


            NSError *error = nil;
            NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                      error:&error];

          int success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];


            if(success == 1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
            } else {

                NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
                [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
            }

        }
```

Comment: if you need the modification I ask here

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xgd474if5vrjp5s/EduTime.zip?dl=0 please check

Comment: @AnkurKumawat - can you give the sample user ID password

Comment: user id- 1000710017 , pwd- XM0MB

Comment: @HERE I GET SUCCESS BRO, ADD MY ANSWER YOU GET OUTPUT

Comment: I added but some error show " status code declare the selector"

Comment: @AnkurKumawat - EVERYTHING IS CLEAR, YOU CAN DOWNLOAD HERE https://www.dropbox.com/s/vzjjjkebx2v9nft/EduTime%202.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thank you so much dear sir, its working very good, thanks a lot.

Comment: @AnkurKumawat - what the change you found

Comment: If you post your full answer,it will helpful for everyone brother.

Answer (score 1):

Ankur kumawat I tried your coding and Brother @Anbu.karthik answer in iOS 9.I got few warnings.First I post Anbu.Karthik brother answer.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sixthsenseit.com/school/project/ios/login.php"]];


//create the Method "GET" or "POST"
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Pass The String to server(YOU SHOULD GIVE YOUR PARAMETERS INSTEAD OF MY PARAMETERS)
NSString *strUserId = @"1000710017";
NSString *strPassword = @"XM0MB";

NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"loginid=%@&loginpassword=%@",strUserId,strPassword, nil];

//Check The Value what we passed
NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", userUpdate);

//Convert the String to Data
NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Apply the data to the body
[request setHTTPBody:data1];

//Create the response and Error
NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                  JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                  error:&error];

int success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];


        if(success == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
        } else {

            NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
            [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
        }
```

Above is brother Anbu.Karthik answer.I tried that and it shows me the warnings.

Warnings are

> 'sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:' is deprecated: first
>   deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use [NSURLSession
>   dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:] (see NSURLSession.h

Then

> Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long _Nullable' to 'int'

As I get warning I want to remove warning and

> I must use 
>    NSURLSession with dataTask because sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:' is deprecated in iOS 9.0

Then I modified the code.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sixthsenseit.com/school/project/ios/login.php"]];

NSString *strUserId = @"1000710017";
NSString *strPassword = @"XM0MB";

NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"loginid=%@&loginpassword=%@",strUserId,strPassword, nil];

//create the Method "GET" or "POST"
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Convert the String to Data
NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Apply the data to the body
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:data1];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
if(httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
{
      NSError *parseError = nil;
      NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
      NSLog(@"The response is - %@",responseDictionary);
      NSInteger success = [[responseDictionary objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
      if(success == 1)
      {
         NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
      }
      else
      {
         NSLog(@"Login FAILURE");
      }
}
else
{
     NSLog(@"Error");     
}
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

The printed result is

```
The response is - {
success = 1;
}
```

And

```
Login SUCCESS
```

Now above my code works perfectly:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in view Controller file:

```
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                        options:kNilOptions
                                        error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@",dict);        

    if (dict)
    {
        NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"success"]];
    }

 output:  1 // successfully
or
  0 // Unsccssfully
NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"error_message"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this :

```
    - (IBAction)Login:(id)sender {
    if([[self.user_id text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.password text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {



    } else {

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sixthsenseit.com/school/project/ios/login.php"]];


        //create the Method "GET" or "POST"
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        //Pass The String to server(YOU SHOULD GIVE YOUR PARAMETERS INSTEAD OF MY PARAMETERS)
        NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"loginid=%@&loginpassword=%@&",_user_id.text,_password.text, nil];



        //Check The Value what we passed
        NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", userUpdate);

        //Convert the String to Data
        NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //Apply the data to the body
        [request setHTTPBody:data1];

        //Create the response and Error
        NSError *err;
        NSURLResponse *response;

        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

       Dictionary *dictResponce = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                            options:kNilOptions
                                            error:&error];        

        if (dictResponce)
        {
            NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"success"]];

    if (status == "1"){
    //Push to home view controller
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Home_page" sender:self];
    }
    else{
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"error_message"]]);
    }

        }
    else{
    NSLog(@"faield to connect");
    }

    }
    }
```